# Avoid duplicate entry in firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the 'word' field in my firestore and i don't wan't users to be entering the same words that is already there in the cloud firestore. How can i do that?

This is my database image: [Fire_store image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv7aF.png)
I don't wan't the values for word to be duplicated.

Database.dart:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/models/user.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/screens/home/loged_home.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/services/auth.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/services/database.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/shared/app_bar.dart';
    import 'package:kopala_dictionary/shared/forms.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    
    class PostData extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _PostDataState createState() => _PostDataState();
    }
    
    class _PostDataState extends State<PostData> {
      String word = '';
      String englishTranslation = '';
      String bembaTranslation = '';
    
      final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
      final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
      final DatabaseService _collections = DatabaseService();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: UnloggedBar(),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextFormField(
                          decoration:
                              textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: 'Word'),
                          validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                              ? 'The word field must not be blank!'
                              : null,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              word = val[0].toUpperCase() + val.substring(1);
                            });
                          }),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        maxLines: 4,
                        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                            ? 'The English translation field must not be blank!'
                            : null,
                        decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            hintText: 'English translation'),
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            englishTranslation = val;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      TextFormField(
                        maxLines: 4,
                        validator: (val) => val.isEmpty
                            ? 'The Bemba translation field must not be blank!'
                            : null,
                        decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                            hintText: 'Bemba Translation'),
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            bembaTranslation = val;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      RaisedButton.icon(
                          color: Colors.green[800],
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                              final loggeduser = Provider.of<User>(context);
                              dynamic insert = await DatabaseService().insertData(
                                  word,
                                  englishTranslation,
                                  bembaTranslation,
                                  loggeduser.uid,
                                  DateTime.now());
    
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => LoggedInUserHome()),
                              );
                            }
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                          label: Text(
                            'POST NOW',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          ))
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I have tried searching but i couldn't find the answers on the internet, only found for Java-Script.

Comment: you can retrieve the words data from firestore before loading the form, and implement equality condition in validator field

Comment: I don't know how to do that please

Comment: create 'DatabaseService().getWordData' method which retrieved the current user word value from firestore, then store the retrieved word value locally and use it in the valiadtion field

Comment: What this this `DatabaseService`? is it your code or some framework? I don't see any import for this class...